# how to find out x and y offset when trying to drag/move an element in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, offset

I am using

```
builder.moveToElement(element).moveByOffset(x,y).click().build().perform();
```

In above function I am not sure of values of X and Y, so I have to run test several times to find out the correct values of X and Y.

Example: first I will try with 5, 5 then if I see its little more towards right than 5, 10 and so on.

Is their a way to find it one go?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to get exact x & y coordinate & then try your code

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath("x-path"));
Point point = ele.getLocation();
int xcord = point.getX();
int ycord = point.getY();
```

Comment: It wouldn't work because unless I hover it correctly the second wouldn't get activated. So I want to do it manually see it and hardcode it

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow the below details.

1. If you are using Chrome Browser (use plug in "Cordinates") or Firefox browser (use plug in "Web Developer -> Display Ruler").
2. After fetching the cordinates from these plug ins, you can use them in your action class for drag and drop.
3. Please be mindful that, once the action is done, you should put offset to ZERO.

e.g: if in first attempt I have tried to click any element preset at (60,20), then before making the second attempt to click anywhere else, I should set the offset as (-60, -20).
Else you can find the second coordinates and perform the plus minus calculations before attempting to click on that.

Comment: x-offset- horizontal offset. A negative value means moving the mouse left.

y-offset- vertical offset. A negative value means moving the mouse down.

Comment: Before anybody else takes the comment above as granted: Please double check! I believe that for the y-offset- vertical offset: A POSITIVE value means moving the mouse down.

Comment: @JackMiller I tried this again in my system and found that POSITIVE value means mouse up. Kindly check in firefox ruler also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get coordinates by program itself

```
//set x and y limits to your webelement size
WebElement element = //your element;
actions = new Actions(remoteDriver);

for (int x = 0; x < element.getSize().getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < getSize().getHeight(); y++) {
   actions.moveToElement(element).moveByOffset(x, y).click().build().perform();

    if ( //your condition ) {
      System.out.println("X and Y when condition satisified  are" + x " and " + y);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

In my experience , the offset values are **nearly equal or in range to half of pixel values of particular point** to click in webelement
ie for my full screen close button for video of 1300*700 playing browser , offset value to full screen close button was x=550 and y=320. Try limiting in that range. Smaller Web Elements means it is much easier to find.